# Why are the functions defined for this generic interface ambiguous?

Tags: generics, interface, fortran

I am trying to create four functions for a single interface, cons. Here is my code in a file called `test_module.f90`

```
module test_module
  type,public :: atom
     character(:),allocatable :: type
     class(*),allocatable :: value
  end type atom
  type,public :: list
     private
     class(*),allocatable :: first
     class(*),allocatable :: rest
  end type list


  interface cons
     module procedure cons_atom_atom
     module procedure cons_list_list
     module procedure cons_atom_list
     module procedure cons_list_atom
  end interface cons

  private :: cons_atom_atom
  private :: cons_list_list
  private :: cons_atom_list
  private :: cons_list_atom

contains
  elemental function cons_atom_atom(a1,a2) result (new_list)
    type(atom),intent(in) :: a1
    type(atom),intent(in) :: a2
    type(list) :: new_list

    allocate(new_list%first,source=a1)
    allocate(new_list%rest,source=a2)
    return
  end function cons_atom_atom

  elemental function cons_list_list(l1,l2) result (new_list)
    type(list),intent(in) :: l1
    type(list),intent(in) :: l2
    type(list) :: new_list

    allocate(new_list%first,source=l1)
    allocate(new_list%rest,source=l2)
    return
  end function cons_list_list

  elemental function cons_atom_list(a,l) result (new_list)
    type(atom),intent(in) :: a
    type(list),intent(in) :: l
    type(list) :: new_list

    allocate(new_list%first,source=a)
    allocate(new_list%rest,source=l)

  end function cons_atom_list

  elemental function cons_list_atom(l,a) result (new_list)
    type(list),intent(in) :: l
    type(atom),intent(in) :: a
    type(list) :: new_list

    allocate(new_list%first,source=l)
    allocate(new_list%rest,source=a)

  end function cons_list_atom

end module test_module

program main
  use test_module
end program main
```

Here are the results of compilation:

```
$ gfortran test_module.f90
test_module.f90:46:2:

   46 |   elemental function cons_atom_list(a,l) result (new_list)
      |  1
......
   56 |   elemental function cons_list_atom(l,a) result (new_list)
      |  2
Error: Ambiguous interfaces in generic interface 'cons' for 'cons_atom_list' at (1) and 'cons_list_atom' at (2)
```

fyi:

```
$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (Homebrew GCC 9.2.0_1) 9.2.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ uname -a
Darwin Jupiter 17.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0: Thu Dec 20 21:47:19 PST 2018; root:xnu-4570.71.22~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

I've followed the patterns I saw in [iso_varying_string.f90](http://www.astro.wisc.edu/~townsend/resource/download/code/iso_varying_string_1.2.f90). For example, the `insert` interface.

Why are `cons_atom_list` and `cons_list_atom` functions considered ambiguous? It seems as if the the order of arguments is irrelevant?

Comment: How does the compiler resolve `CONS(L=list, A=atom)`?  In other words, the use of keywords cannot not be resolved, because you have used the same dummy arguments in the two ambiguous functions.

Comment: Is there a way to disable keyword arguments and force only positional arguments?

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response.  I was out of town for work.  There is no way to disable keywords.  Keywords are a fundamental feature of Fortran's handling of functions and subroutines.  I tested your code by changing `CONS_ATOM_LIST` to use the keywords `LL` and AA` (ie., I used unique keywords).  I don't know if this is a gfortran extension or standard conforming when resolving functions references.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My solution ended up being to ignore types altogether for the arguments to cons and make it instead a function of two class(*) arguments.  This collapsed all of the functions in the cons interface into just a single cons function, eliminating the interface entirely.